# What is required printf precision for a __float128 to not lose information?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, glibc

I'm trying to printf a __float128 using libquadmath, eg:

```
quadmath_snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "%.30Qg", f);
```

With the following three constaints:

1. The output must match the following production:

   ```
    number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]

    decimal-point = %x2E       ; .

    digit1-9 = %x31-39         ; 1-9

    e = %x65 / %x45            ; e E

    exp = e [ minus / plus ] 1*DIGIT

    frac = decimal-point 1*DIGIT

    int = zero / ( digit1-9 *DIGIT )

    minus = %x2D               ; -

    plus = %x2B                ; +

    zero = %x30                ; 0
   ```
2. Given any input __float128 "i" that has been printfed to a string matching the above production "s" and and then "s" is scanfed back into a __float128 "j" - "i" must be bitwise identical to "j" - ie no information should be lost.  For at least some values this is not possible (NaN, Infinity), what is the complete list of those values?
3. There should be no other string satisfying the above two criteria, that is shorter than the candidate.

Is there a quadmath_snprintf format string that satisfies the above (1, 3 and 2 when possible)?  If so what is it?

What are the values of __float128 that cannot be represented accurately enough to satisfy point 2 by the above production? (eg Nan, +/-Infinity, etc) How do I detect if a __float128 is holding one of these values?

Comment: There are an infinite set of decimal numbers that cannot be represented accurately in __float128.  Any that have more than 34 significant digits.  Your format specifier produces random digits for any absolute number >= 1E5.  Your approach is deeply flawed, possibly started by thinking that you need __float128 to solve a problem.

Comment: The fact that there are an infinite number of decimal numbers that cannot be represented accurately in __float128 is irrelevant, point 2 merely requires that the decimal representation is precise enough such that when read back and rounded it's the same as what went in.  I am aware the format specifier is incorrect, the question asks for a correct one.  My "approach" is fine and you have no idea what problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on x86, then the GCC __float128 type is a software implementation of the IEEE 754-2008 binary128 format. The IEEE 754 standard requires that a binary -> char -> binary roundtrip recovers the original value if the character representation contains 36 significant (decimal) digits. Thus the format string `%.36Qg` ought to do it.

It is not required that a NaN roundtrip recover the original bitwise value.

As for your requirement #3, libquadmath does not contain code for this kind of "shortest representation" formatting, e.g. in the spirit of the Steele & White paper or the code by David Gay.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that binary fraction 0.1111...1 (128 ones); also equal to 1-1/2**128 will produce the largest number of overflows upon conversion to decimal. Convert that value to decimal (I don't have a bignum package right now), count the number of digits, add 2-3 on top of that and you should be safe. I don't have a mathematical proof that this is enough, though.

If precision of I/O is important, I'd prefer outputting the float as a hex string. Accurate floating-point IO is hard to get right, and the library might be buggy in that respect.

Comment: “0.1111...1 (128 ones)” is not representable as a `__float128`, but even fixing the 128 into the 113 that you might have meant, I don't see why this number should be a worst case. The decimal representation of worst-case candidate would start with a leading 1, instead of a leading 9.